# Weird issue with passing value from user control to parent page

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, user-controls

I have a user control which contains some controls and its put to a parent page.

On the click of a server side button in the User Control, I am invoking a method.

I need to pass a value when the above button has been clicked to the parent page's JavaScript function.

I created a private variable and its public property in the user control.

Assigned some string to the public property when the button is clicked.

In the parent aspx.cs page, I retrieved the value of the above property by the user control's ID in Page_Load and assigned it to a hidden variable defined in the parent aspx page.

Now, when I'm trying to get the value of this hidden variable in the Parent page JavaScript function, its coming as empty.

Any other method to pass values, first I thought of Session var's but then Session var's won't be effective in JavaScript.

Below is my code which I have tried:

UserControl ascx.cs page:

```
private string _button1Clicked;
        public string Button1Clicked
        {
            get { return _button1Clicked; }
            set { _button1Clicked = value; }
        }

public void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs s)
        {
            PopulateOtherViews();
            Button1Clicked = "Button1Clicked";           
        }
```

Parent page aspx.cs page:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
              hiddenButton1Click.Value = filter.Button1Clicked;   
            }
```

Parent Page aspx page:

```
<input type="hidden" id="hiddenButton1Click" runat="server" />
    function PageLoad()
    {
    var x = document.getElementById('hiddenButton1Click');//x.Value is "", empty
    if (x.value == "Button1Clicked") 
                         {
                            doOpenFilterCollapse();
                        }
                        else {
                            doCloseFilterCollapse();
                        }
    }
}
```

Experts please assist over here. Any pointers will be highly helpful.

Regards

Anurag

Comment: Your hiddenButton1Click is runat="server". I think you need in javascript call it with '<%=hiddenButton1Click .ClientID%>'

Comment: Let me try to add ClientID too..Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this in JavaScript

```
var x = document.getElementById('<%= hiddenButton1Click.ClientID %>');
```

instead of this

```
var x = document.getElementById('hiddenButton1Click');
```

Comment: Let me try to add ClientID too..Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your hidden ctl is `runat="server"` so if you inspect the page elements you will see somthing like `ctl00_` + control id.
So in your current javascript will not find `hiddenButton1Click` so you need

`'<%=hiddenButton1Click .ClientID%>'`